# Facebook payment with automatic currency conversion, what is reported?

Tags: facebook, facebook-payments

Say that a user of my Facebook Game initiates a payment for a product that is only priced in *EUR*, which Facebook then converts to *USD* for them. When I fetch this Payment from the Facebook Graph API, what's the currency reported in its `charge` action, *EUR* or *USD*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through experimenting, I've found that the reported currency is one that is specified in the product Open Graph page (in this case *EUR*).